# Surface keyboard suddenly stopped working

Tags: keyboard, microsoft-surface

Suddenly my Surface Pro keyboard stopped working. The <kbd>Fn</kbd> key stays lit. The mouse pad works but the keys won’t work. Basically nothing can be typed. Keep in mind the Surface works fine. Oh one thing the keyboard stays lit and does not go to sleep.

Help please. Hate to spend money on a new keyboard.

Comment: Which version Surface Pro? What happens if you disconnect it and reconnect it? What about putting the machine to sleep (short press of power key) and then waking it up again? Full power off/reboot? If you connect a USB keyboard, does that work?

Comment: Have you tried the steps found here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4023473/surface-troubleshoot-your-surface-type-cover-or-keyboard ?

Answer (score 3):

I haven been using surface pro from last 2 years & I have come across this issue several times. hopefully this information will help you.

1. Detach, clean and reattach your surface type cover
   Sometimes dirt and dust over surface keyboard connector can lead to surface keyboard not working problem. A simple cleaning of connector can resolve this problem.
2. Fix Ease of access Setting
   Search “ease of access” in the search box on the taskbar
   Select Ease of access keyboard settings
   Under the keyboard setting make sure that sticky key & filter key both are off.
3. Perform Force shutdown & restart
   For Surface go, Surface pro 6, Surface pro (5th Gen)

   You need to press & hold the power button for 10 seconds it will turn the Surface off.
   Now press the power button & release, it will turn your surface on again. 
   If it does not work, to shut down & restart your surface completely 
   you keep power button pressed until surface restart & you see the windows logo. It will take approx. 20 seconds.

   For Surface pro, Surface pro 2, Surface pro 3, Surface pro 4 perform these steps to force shutdown & restart the device

   You need to press & hold the power button for 10 seconds it will turn the Surface off.
   Now press the power button & release it will turn your surface on again & you will be able to see surface logo.

   If it does not work then perform two button shutdown steps as below to ensure your surface turns off completely.

   1. Press & hold the power button for approx. 30 seconds & then release it.
   2. After this press power & volume up button at the same time and keep it pressed for 15 seconds, even after if you see surface logo keep it pressed for 15 seconds.
   3. Wait for 10 seconds after releasing the button.
   4. Now press the power button & release, it will turn your surface on again.
4. Update or reinstall surface type cover driver
5. Check for windows file error
   Before starting these steps, ensure that your surface is plugged into power because this may take a while.

   1. Search “command prompt” in the search box on the taskbar
   2. Select “Run as administrator” even if you are logged as Admin
   3. You may get a warning prompt, tap ok.
   4. In the command line type SFC/scannow and tap enter
   5. This will start process of scanning
6. Reset the Surface and Fix Surface Keyboard Not Working Problem
   If you need any further detail on [Surface Pro keyboard stopped working](https://e-methodstechnologies.com/guide-to-fix-surface-keyboard-not-working-issue/), you may refer this resource which I found while searching when I had same problem

Comment: In steps 2 and 5,  how do you search in the search box *if you can’t type anything?*

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' : One can use the on screen keyboard inbuilt in Windows 10 and as the OP mentioned that the trackpad works,it won’t be a hassle.

Comment: @G-Man Says 'Reinstate Monica' - Microsoft Surface is a series of touchscreen-based personal computers, so it would not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, be sure to have a valid Internet connection as this method will download drivers from Microsoft.

1. Go to Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers
2. Open the Properties of "Surface Type Cover" and select the Hardware tab.
3. From this tab, open the properties of each associated device. Uninstall each device, deleting drivers when the option is available.
4. After all items have been uninstalled (The Surface Type Cover Properties Hardware tab will NOT update as you do this), You can close the open windows.
5. Next, Open Device Manager: "Scan for Hardware Changes"
6. Expand the following groups: Firmware & Keyboards.
7. Under Firmware, update all drivers using "Search Automatically for updated driver software"
8. Under Keyboards, you should see several "HID Keyboard Device". There's no quick way to identify which is the Surface Type Cover. I performed driver updates as noted before in Firmware for each Keyboard until the Surface Type Cover was installed.

That's it. No reboot was necessary. Keyboard started working right away.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you hold a key down for a long time? I just experienced this on my Surface Book - my `Caps` LED was lit and the touchpad worked fine, but the keyboard appeared unresponsive - even after attaching/detaching - despite having worked fine moments earlier. I eventually discovered that my 1 year-old had [activated *Filter Keys* by holding down the `Shift` key](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/155519/using-the-shortcut-key-to-enable-filterkeys). I was able to verify this by holding down keys and seeing that they did, after a long time, actually produce output. Reverting the setting restored normal operation.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue today on my Surface running Windows 10 and here's what I did to correct it (I suspect only steps 6 - 9 really mattered):

1. Since I was able to move the mouse, I clicked Start | [Power Icon] |
   Shutdown.
2. I unplugged all USB devices attached to the keyboard and removed the power cord.
3. While the unit was off I pressed the [Up Arrow] key at top right hand-side of the keyboard to force-eject the touchscreen and separate it from the keyboard. The key lighted up orange and a clicking noise was heard, indicating I could pull off the touchscreen (even though the entire unit had been turned off!)
4. I turned the tablet (touchscreen) on.
5. I put the touchscreen back together with the keyboard and tested again. However, that still didn't seem to correct the issue.
6. I hit the [Up Arrow] key at top right-hand side of the keyboard to eject the touchscreen again (while the entire unit was still on this time).
7. I waited about a minute.
8. I put the touchscreen and keyboard back together again.
9. This time everything was working again!

One thing I learned in retrospect later was that the keyboard malfunction seemed to coincide with the moment I plugged in an external USB 3.0 HDD that malfunctioned (it never came online and I even got a yellow tip message on the system tray at the bottom right of the screen indicating that a USB device was malfunctioning.) It seems that maybe that device knocked out the keyboard temporarily. Perhaps the faulty keyboard was due to the drive just not spinning up in time (I know it didn't spin up because I didn't hear it whirring as it normally does.) I guess that sort of paralyzed the keyboard device and it only cleared up after it reset itself somehow through the steps I took above. This is just my guess! When I got the keyboard working again per the above steps, I plugged the drive back in and this time it did spin up. Everything is fine now.

Comment: This sounds like you're talking about a Surface Book. The question is about a Surface Pro.

Comment: Sorry, yes. This is a Surface Book here.

Answer (score -1):

If the volume up and volume down buttons are working, maybe the "filter keys" are the answer for Your issue. Try to press right Shift for 8-10 seconds

Answer (score -2):

in my case the problem was a driver  in 1903 update. it installed a  wacom driver in human interface devices. roll it back to the genric 'usb input device'[microsoft 2006 v 10.0.18362.175